# Is there a way to increase the time out on a callback function in nodejs?

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.7

I am running a simple nodejs web application that executes a Python 2.7 script using the module python-shell. However, since this script takes too long to execute, around 3 minutes, the function fails with an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error.

The function executes at the end, since Python still runs it in the background but the web application crashes.

```
    generatePPage: (req, res) => {

        const ps = require('python-shell');

        let nombre = req.params.id;
        var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
        var options = {
            pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python2.7',
            args: [nombre], 
        };

        var users =  ps.PythonShell.run('./generateDetail.py', options, function (err, results) {
            if (err){throw err;} 
            console.log('The results: %j', results);
            res.render('success.ejs', {
                title: 'Edit  Project'
                ,project: ''
                ,message: 'Success'
            });

          });

    },
```

How could I force it to wait longer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use setTimeout.
Check this link for more information: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Node.js_Tutorial/0270__Node.js_setTimeout_setInterval.htm
And also, check out this link: https://nodejs.org/ar/docs/guides/timers-in-node/

Comment: That would only further delay the execution, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The way to do it is to assign the return value of calling the listen function to a const and then assign a new timeout value in milliseconds.

```js
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
server.timeout = 300000;
```